# How to call /invoke android's internal task manager (Task Switcher UI) by our code?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to build an app of which one module is to invoke android's internal task switcher (which gets invoked by long pressing home key) by my own code.

I have seen it possible in **CleanMaster** app.

I just want that simple functionality in that module. Which class / Activity to go for?